# Nuget packages keep failing on wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nuget, package-managers

I have had an issue over the past few weeks with nuget package manager.  Basically everytime I try to install a package it gives me and error like this:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Install-Package:
> Could not install package 'WPtoolkit 4.2013.06.11'. You are trying to         install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not
> contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I get a similar issue with every package I try to install even though the packages clearly state they support wp8.

This issue is getting very frustrating and is making the nuget package manager feature all but useless for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update package manager